# Rotation in physics

Tags: syntax, physics

I have a mathematica problem in theoretical physics:

There is a rotation axis $\vec{n}$ with $|\vec{n}|=1$. Each other vector $\vec{v}$  can be seperated in relation to $\vec{n}$ in a parallel part and a part vertically to $\vec{n}$:

$$\vec{v}=\vec{v}_{||}+\vec{v}_\perp$$

Furthermore:

$$\vec{v}_{||}=(\vec{v}\cdot\vec{n}) \, \vec{n}$$

$$\vec{v}_\perp=\vec{v}-\vec{v}_{||}$$

A rotation around rotation axis $\vec{n}$ with a rotation angle $\alpha$ is described by :

$$D_{\alpha\vec{n}}\vec{v}=\vec{v}_{||}+\cos(\alpha) \, \vec{v}_\perp+\sin(\alpha) \, (\vec{n}\times\vec{v}) \tag{1}$$

a) How could a procedure look like, that calculates the parallel $\vec{v}_{||}$ and a vertical part $\vec{v}_\perp$for vectors $\vec{n}$ and $\vec{v}$ ?

b) How could a procedure look like that turns a vector $\vec{v}$ usig equation (1) for a given rotation axis $\vec{n}$ and rotation angle $\alpha$?

Comment: Give an example n, v, and alpha or you won't get much much help. Also look up dot and cross products in the help pages and give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generating random normal, vector, and angle:

```
n = RandomPoint[Sphere[]];
v = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3];
α = RandomReal[{-Pi, Pi}];
```

Computing the rotated vector:

```
vpar = n n.v;
vperp = v - vpar;

vrot = vpar + Cos[α] vperp + Sin[α] Cross[n, v];
```

Let's check correctness by comparing vs. `RotationMatrix`:

```
RotationMatrix[α, n].v == vrot
```

> True

Comment: Be blessed Henrik! Thank you

Comment: You're welcome.